# Creacion de JSON desde Interfaz con C# y Blazor

Tags: c#, json, blazor

Soy nueva y estoy trabajando con `blazor` y `c#`, mi consulta es, estoy creando un `JSON` con una estructura específica a partir de los datos que se ingresen en la interfaz del `blazor`.

Aquí creo el `JSON` y le asigno los valores a cada atributo desde una clase, la estructura que les pongo ya me arma el `JSON` como lo deseo, pero hay algunos atributos que no deben quedar siempre en el `JSON` según lo que el usuario escoja.

En el ejemplo tengo un selector en el cual escogí que el atributo tipo sea texto, entonces el atributo render no se debe que mostrar en esa parte de la estructura. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?, agradezco su ayuda

```
private void GenerateJSON()
 {
     var surveyObject = new
     {
         id = config.id,
         tenant_id = config.tenant_id,
         title = config.title,
         surveyId = config.surveyId,
         titleWelcomeMessage = config.titleWelcomeMessage,
         welcomeMessage = config.welcomeMessage,
         exitMessageTitle = config.exitMessageTitle,
         exitMessage = config.exitMessage,
         type = config.type,
         enabled = config.enabledTrue ? true : false,
         draft = config.draft,
         channelId = config.channelId,
         progressBarConfig = new
         {
             titleType = config.titleType
         },
         expirationSurveyConfig = new
         {
             time = config.time,
             initialAlertConfig = new
             {
                 title = config.titleAlertInitial,
                 description = config.description
             },
             finalAlertConfig = new
             {
                 title = config.FinaltitleAlert,
                 description = config.Finaldescription
             }
         },
         surveys = questions.Select(q => new
         { 
             id = q.Id,
             Order = q.Id,
             Render = (questions.Count > 0) ? GetSelectedRender(q.selectedType) : null,
             Type = (questions.Count > 0) ? GetSelectedTypeText(q.selectedType) : null,
             Category = q.Category,
             // Alias
             Ask = q.ask,
             Alias = q.Alias,
             placeholder = q.placeholder,
             insightsConfig = new {
                 needInsights = q.insightsConfigTrue,
                 maxChoices =   q.maxChoices,
                 threshold = new {
                         min = q.thresholdMin,
                         max =  q.thresholdMax
                 },
             },
             Range = (q.minNumber != 0) ? new
             {
                 min = q.minNumber,
                 max = q.maxNumber,
                 Default = q.defaultNumber,
                 label = q.labelOne + "|" + q.labelTwo
             } : new object { },
             List = q.ListValue.Select(lv => new
             {
                 value = lv.value,
                 displayName = lv.DisplayName
             }),
             Description = Description,
             required = q.isSelected1 ? true : false,
             options = q.option.Select(a => new
             {

                 Id = a.IdOption,
                 Alias = a.AliasOption,
                 Ask = a.TextOption,
                 Type = (q.option != null && q.option.Count > 0) ? GetSelectedTypeOption(a.selectedTypeOption) : null,
                 Render = (q.option != null && q.option.Count > 0) ? GetSelectedRenderOption(a.selectedTypeOption) : null,
                 dataSource = selectedTypeOption == "2" ? new
                 {
                     method = "GET",
                     enpointOption = a.enpointOption,
                     contentType = "application/json"
                 } : new object { },

                 List = a.ValueList.Select(v => new
                 {
                     value = v.valueId,
                     displayName = v.DisplayName
                 }),
                 listItemsConfig = a.selectedTypeOption == "2" ? new
                 {
                     selectionReasons = a.ValueReasonsList.Select(rv => new
                     {
                         value = rv.value,
                         displayName = rv.DisplayName
                     }),
                     selectedItemConfig = new
                     {
                         headerText = a.headerText,
                         options = new[]
                         {
                                 new
                                 {
                                     type = a.type,
                                     ask = a.askItem,
                                     ReasonsList = a.ValueReasonsList.Select(rl => rl.value).ToArray(),
                                 }
                     }
                     },
                     customItemConfig = new
                     {
                         trigger = new
                         {
                             title = a.titleText,
                             featherIcon = a.featherIcon
                         },
                         headerText = a.customheder,
                         options = new[]
                         {
                                 new
                                 {
                                     type = a.type,
                                     ask = a.customaskItem,
                                     ReasonsList = a.ValueReasonsList.Select(rl => rl.value).ToArray(),
                                 }
                     }
                     }
                 } : null,
                 Range = a.selectedTypeOption == "1" ? (a.minNumberOption != 0) ? new
                 {
                     min = a.minNumberOption,
                     max = a.maxNumberOption,
                     Default = a.defaultNumberOption,
                     label = a.labelOption + "|" + a.labelOption1
                 } : new object { } : a.selectedTypeOption == "2" ? new
                 {
                     min = a.minNumberRangeOption,
                     max = a.maxNumberRangeOption
                 } : new object { },
                 Order = q.Id
             }),
             flows = q.isSelectedFlowYes == true ? new[]
             {
                 new
                 {
                     id = q.Id,
                     questionOrder = q.Id,
                     behavior = "Dropdown",
                     Operator = "OR",
                     values = new[]
                     {
                         q.ListValueFlow.Select(vf => vf.valueFlow).ToArray(),
                     },
                 }
         } : new object[]{}
         }),
         theme = new
         {
             Id = ThemeSurvey.Id,
             name = ThemeSurvey.name,
             background_color = ThemeSurvey.background_color,
             background_image = ThemeSurvey.background_image,
             alternative_color = ThemeSurvey.alternative_color,
             secondary_color = ThemeSurvey.secondary_color,
             primary_color = ThemeSurvey.primary_color,
             font = ThemeSurvey.font,
             custom_css = "",
             logo = ThemeSurvey.logo
         }
     }; 
     
     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
     {
         WriteIndented = true,
         Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,    
     };
     jsonResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(surveyObject, options);
     
 }
```

Esta es una de las clases que estoy utilizando, (Tengo mas clases)

```
namespace SurveyJson.Data
{
public class ConfigurationInitial
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tenant_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string surveyId { get; set; }
    public string titleWelcomeMessage { get; set; } = "Su opinión es nuestra prioridad";
    public string welcomeMessage { get; set; } = "";
    public string exitMessageTitle { get; set; } = "";
    public string exitMessage { get; set; } = "";
    public string type { get; set; } = "QR";
    public bool enabledTrue { get; set; } 
    public bool enabledFalse { get; set; }
    public string draft { get; set; } = "false";
    public string channelId { get; set; } = "";
    public string titleType { get; set; }
    public bool expirationTrue { get; set; }
    public bool expirationFalse { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public string titleAlertInitial { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string FinaltitleAlert { get; set; }
    public string Finaldescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tu quieres que si `typo == "texto"` entonces `render` no se muestre en el JSON resultante???? Otra cosa que no entiendo es porque retornas un objeto de clase anónima en lugar de tener una clase tipada como `ConfigurationInitial` y porque tienes esta clase distinta a lo que retornas. Si tu clase `ConfigurationInitial` fuera la misma del retorno te ahorras todo ese seteo enorme que tienes

Comment: Hola Si eso es lo que quiero, que cuando typo == "texto" entonces render no se muestre en el JSON resultante, cual es el objeto de clase anonima que dices que retorno?, es que como mencione hasta ahora estoy empezando ConfigurationInitial solo hace una parte del json hay mas clases que traen su parte del JSON, ese json esta dentro de la pagina blazor ya que desde ahi mando los valores,